# Trouble to scrape etoile rating with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some information on this website : https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com

Here's my script so far :

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

urls = ["https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=2",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=3",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=4",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=5",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=6",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=7",
        "https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page=8"]

comms = []
notes = []

for url in urls : 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")


    commentary = soup.find_all('p', class_='review-content__text')

    for container in commentary:
        comm  = container.text
        comms.append(comm)

    ratings = soup.find_all('div', class_='star-rating star-rating--medium')

    for container2 in ratings:
        rating = container2.text
        notes.append(rating)



    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'comms' : comms,
        'notes' : notes})

    data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')


#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

And here's my result : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPkIK.png)

I obtained the commentary but not the rating, I can't quite figure it out how to obtain it.

Here's the code source : [codesource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ohf0.png)

I would like to have : "1 étoile : mauvais" but the structure is tricky.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to fix here:

1. to get the ratings associated with the review, I would actually grab the parent tag (actually it's 2 levels up) from the `'p', class_='review-content__text'`. That way within that element, you can then grab the review text, and grab the rating.

The rating aren't actual text, they are images. So you can grab the `<img>` tag, and look at the `alt` attribute to get that, which gives you stars/ratings.

2. You need `data = pd.DataFrame({ 'comms' : comms, 'notes' : notes})` to be outside the loop of urls. Otherwise each page is going to overwrite the dataframe from the previous iteration.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

root_url = 'https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com'
urls = [ '{root}?page={i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in range(1,9) ]

comms = []
notes = []

for url in urls : 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")


    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='review-content')

    for container in commentary:
        comm  = container.find('p', class_='review-content__text').text.strip()
        comms.append(comm)
        
        rating = container.find('div', class_='star-rating star-rating--medium').find('img')['alt']
        notes.append(rating)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes})

data['comms'] = data['comms'].str.replace('\n', '')


#print(data.head())
data.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (data)
                                                 comms                  notes
0    Suite à un achat effectué fin novembre, j’ai e...     1 étoile : mauvais
1    Aujourd'hui dans le magasin de Beaucouzé Anger...     1 étoile : mauvais
2    A FUIR! Sur les deux commandes passée : - La p...     1 étoile : mauvais
3    Si vous avez une réclamation évitez le Jardila...     1 étoile : mauvais
4    Quelle honten ! J'ai acheté une nappe ce weeke...     1 étoile : mauvais
..                                                 ...                    ...
139  Pour moi c'est zéro, cher, personnel pas très ...     1 étoile : mauvais
140  J'ai acheté deux serres chauffantes avec therm...      3 étoiles : moyen
141  Magasin agréable à Maurepas.Vendeurs sympathiq...  5 étoiles : excellent
142  Il y a vraiment beaucoup de choix et c'est un ...  5 étoiles : excellent
143  Grâce à vos sélections mon jardin ressemble à ...  5 étoiles : excellent

[144 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful answer, I will check it asap :)

Comment: It works ! Thanks. Do you have any ideas to get rid of my urls list and do without ? Because when you have 8 pages, it's ok, but when you have >100 pages, that's tedious.

Comment: I tried this "for i in range(2,8) : 
 results = requests.get("https://fr.trustpilot.com/review/jardiland.com?page={i}")" but it doesn't work, that's overwrite.

Comment: not sure why yours didnt work. but you could just use the same idea to make a list of urls. see above

Comment: It works ! Thanks !! Yeah me neither, I guess I misplace something